# Notes Federated Login not downloading in memory ID file - Entry not found in index

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, lotus-notes, federated, hcl-notes

We have setup Notes federated login to provide a single-signon for Notes clients from Active directory.  and there seem to be a problem when getting the "in memory" ID file from the Vault.

Here is the scenario

1. User start Notes (tried both v9 and V10) for the first time
2. Enter password in the Login screen for the local id file.
3. Message prompt "ID file is now downloaded for Notes Federated Login"
4. User click "OK"  and a new message show up "Server Error - Entry not in index"
5. User click "OK" and then the passsword prompt for the local id file is displayed.

So, in short there seem to be a problem when downloading from the Vault but the error message do not really say much.

We have enabled all the client debug options and checked the server logs but nothing really tells us what is wrong.

All we get is this:

An issue that failed to authenticate was reported from the server / domain server: Entry not in index

[image]

[image]

[image]

Id-file is already in use and can't be changed
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't diagnose the issue from reading your problem description.  I suggest you open a support ticket with the steps to reproduce.  ERR_NOT_FOUND (not found in index) is a very common return value in Domino, often even being benign.  But in the benign cases it is handled by the calling code.

So it's hard to know what method/function threw the error or what the stack was at the time.  Hence the advice to open a support ticket.

Comment: Should my client report it to IBM or to HCL?